# How to join two faces

Tags: modeling

How would I join the two faces as below?:

[image: Two faces]

Using knife, I cut the long edge adjacent to the trapezoid to add vertices, and I also successfully used TinyCAD to add vertices in the same place, but I'm still not able to select only the adjacent edge between the two faces. I can only select the entire edge of the rectangle, not just the adjacent portion. Many thanks in advance if any ideas!

Comment: So you want to join the two faces but not at the corners?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the top edge of the trapezium is most easily done in Vertex mode - select both ends and switch back to Edge mode. But even then, TinyCad is a bit of a long way round, here.

Vertices must somehow be cut (topologically) into the bottom edge of the rectangle, so alternatives include:

- With *Snap* set to 'Active' and 'Vertex' and *Automerge* switched on:
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate the bottom vertices of the rectangle in their edge, and drag them any old where..
- Snap them onto the top vertices of the trapezium

[image]

On the whole though, when modeling, you would want the extra edges in the rectangle. If so..

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and scroll, cut 2 edge-loops into the rectangle
- With *Snap* and *Automerge* set as before, and your Pivot set to 'Median', in Vertex mode, with one of the new loop vertices active...
- <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> the new loops, snapping to one of the top vertices of the trapezium.

[image]

These are by no means the 'right' ways of doing this.. I'm sure you have/will have your own grab-bag of favorite modeling patterns.

Comment: Many thanks, and much appreciated Robin and @Israel Bamidele. Unfortunately, as I'm a beginner, I'm having trouble following your instructions (my fault, not yours!). For starters, I'm unable to perform loop-cuts in the rectangle, only the trapezium.  Do you know why it's not letting me add loop-cuts to the rectangle? (In case it matters, in Object Mode, I can't select the trapezium and rectangle separately. When I click on one, the conjoined shape is selected. Does that mean that I've inadvertently joined the 2 shapes, and if so, could that be interfering with my loop-cut operations?)

Comment: I figured out the loop-cut issue. I had an extra vertex in the rectangle that was throwing things off . . . Now, onto the rest of the exercise! . . .

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way is to make 2 "loop cut" like the last image in the previous answer.

After that, switch to "vertex mode", also turn on " all vertex visible"

Press C to switch to "circle select", select the 1st vertex interception and press ALT M to merge the vertex. Do the same for the 2nd vertex interception.

That should solve the problem